# custom tabbar view shifts down when in and out of a call

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I made custom `TabBar` by adding `UIView` at the bottom of `TabBar` controller.
when in and out of a call, custom `TabBar` position is shifted down by 20 pixels.
What causes this issue?

```
self.customTabBarView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin |         UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

I added auto resizing property when add custom view.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.customTabBarView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
```

this works like a charm.